How to customize auth pages and settings | ABP Framework Blazor
I would like to be able to customize these pages but I can't see anywhere the source code. As far as
As far as I could see, the system uses
@page "/authentication/{action}" @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication @using Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Security

You probably can't.  "ABP offers an opinionated architecture to build enterprise software solutions".  The correct forum for this question is probably https://github.com/abpframework/abp/discussions.  I think the Venn intersection set for people who answer Blazor questions here and ABP framework experts is 0.

https://abp.io/community/articles/how-to-customize-the-login-page-of-an-abp-blazor-application-by4o9yms article to customize auth pages similarly you can change for settings as well. 
if you only need to change the application logic then just extend their service and override via dependency injection using [Dependency(ReplaceServices = true)] 
visit this link to get full details - https://abp.io/docs/latest/framework/fundamentals/dependency-injection?_redirected=B8ABF606AA1BDF5C629883DF1061649A
